# A word "fraught" in a sentence

Tags: word-meaning

Currently reading [**this article,**](https://www.yahoo.com/news/uncharted-brexit-waters-uks-boris-075721411.html), 12th paragraph says,

> Most trade talks take much longer than one year to complete. These particular negotiations are unusually ***fraught*** because of uncertainty surrounding how trade between Northern Ireland and Ireland will be governed once the U.K. is no longer part of the EU.

What definition under my dictionary is the bold italic adjective? ***fraught*** used by?

> 1 a archaic :  carrying as a load :  laden, freighted
>
> b :  well supplied or provided
>
> 2
>   a :  burdened or menaced with
>   
>   
>   endangered, threatened
>
> b :  giving promise or prospect — used with with
>
> c :  accompanied, attended — used with with
>
> 3
>   :  causing or characterized by emotional distress or tension :  uneasy

Or is it the definition as a verb defined as the following?

> **now chiefly Scottish**
>   :  load, freight, fill

I appreciate your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, definition 3 is correct, because the participants are uneasy over the problems caused by the mentioned breakup of the E.U. and U.K.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is one of the most difficult words I've encountered so far.